# Laravel 8 not showing new images

Tags: php, laravel

I have my Laravel 8 project on a shared hosting which uses cPanel. Uploaded my files and database with some records, for old records website displays all the images, but when I upload new images they're not showing up, photos are uploading on a storage folder, but not showing up.

HTML code:

```
<img src="/storage/{{ $post->photo}}"/>
```

This is a link to a stored images:

```
https://website.com/storage/images/
```

PostController image upload:

```
$image = $request->file('photo')->store('images', 'public');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what to you get if you debug $post->image. I'm not familiar with laravel but can you make something like this print_r($post->image). Maybe there has to be a space after the variable.

Comment: That's not what I need

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link`? (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: @erikgaal yes, but didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from here:
[laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/the-storage-link-already-exists-but-i-am-gettin-404-error-when-trying-to-get-a-file-from-the-public-folder)

Solution is to delete the "STORAGE" folder if exists, then run this command line:

```
php artisan storage:link
```